# imagejpeg causing file type 'binary/octet-stream' in GCS

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a GAE php script which rotates a given image (stored in GCS) and then writes it to the same GCS bucket it originates from (all in the same Cloud Platform project).

Everything is working fine - the image is loaded correctly, rotated and save. The problem is, when the image is saved, GCS recognizes it's type as `binary/octet-stream` rather than `image/jpeg`, which causes any public links to automatically download the image file rather then show it directly in the browser.

The code:

```
    $bucket = 'gs://my-bucket-here/';
    $imageRes = imagecreatefromjpeg($bucket . $picName);

    if ($imageRes) {
        $rotate = imagerotate($imageRes, 90, 0);
        imagedestroy($imageRes);
        imagejpeg($rotate, $bucket . "test.jpg");
        imagedestroy($rotate);
    }
```

Any hints on whats causing this? I thought about using Imagick instead but it's not available in GAE...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the content type in context options, in this case you'd need to set it in the default options as there is no way to pass context to the `imagejpeg()` method.

```
$options = [
  'gs' => [
      'Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg',
  ],
];

stream_context_set_default($options);

$bucket = 'gs://my-bucket-here/';
$imageRes = imagecreatefromjpeg($bucket . $picName);

if ($imageRes) {
  $rotate = imagerotate($imageRes, 90, 0);
  imagedestroy($imageRes);
  imagejpeg($rotate, $bucket . "test.jpg");
  imagedestroy($rotate);
}
```

Comment: Facing same issue, but not with php